# Use total number of pages in beamer as counter

Tags: beamer, counters

I'm trying to set a count in latex on the total number of pages:

```
\newcount\mypagecount
\mypagecount=\insertpresentationendpage
```

But whenver I do this, it auto "prints" the total number of pages instead of putting the number as a count. Is there a way to set it as a count?

Here is more precisely what I'm trying to do:

```
\newcount\mypagenum
\newcount\mypagecount
\newdimen\barwidth

\mypagenum=\insertpagenumber
\mypagecount=\insertpresentationendpage
\barwidth=\paperwidth

\multiply\barwidth by \mypagenum                                       
\divide\barwidth by \mypagecount
```

I tried with counters, but that threw errors as well:

```
\newcounter{mypagecount}
\setcounter{mypagecount}{\insertpresentationendpage}
```

Any ideas how I can do the division at the end if I can't use these numbers and/or how to actually use these numbers?

Comment: `\insertpresentationendpage` doesn't expand to a number (it isn't expandable at all), so you can't use it directly in an assignment.

Comment: Also you have a typo, it should be `\insertpagenumber` (you're missing the `s`).

Comment: Fixed the typo for the missing s. I double checked and my code did have the correct `s`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does essentially the same as the current version of `\insertpresentationendpage` of `beamer`, but in a way such that your counter is set instead of the result printed. I also included a proof of concept progress bar output.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\newlength\barwidth
\newlength\tmpbarwidth
\newcount\mypagecount

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\progressbar
  {%
    \ifnum\mypagecount=0
      \ifx\beamer@startpageofappendix\@empty
        \mypagecount=\beamer@endpageofdocument\relax
      \else
        \mypagecount=\beamer@startpageofappendix\relax
        \advance\mypagecount\m@ne
      \fi
      \ifnum\mypagecount=0
        \global\mypagecount=1
      \else
        \global\mypagecount=\mypagecount
      \fi
    \fi
    \begingroup
      \tmpbarwidth\insertpagenumber\barwidth
      \divide\tmpbarwidth\mypagecount
      \rule{\tmpbarwidth}{5pt}%
      \advance\barwidth-\tmpbarwidth
      \textcolor{gray}{\rule{\barwidth}{5pt}}%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\setlength\barwidth{5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \progressbar
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \progressbar
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \progressbar
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \progressbar
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried putting this into my template (in footline) and this isn't working. From what I gather there is no variable that expands to a number?

Comment: @AramPapazian `\beamer@endpageofdocument` and `\beamer@startpageofappendix` both do. Be sure to execute this code late (that's why I put it into the definition of `\progressbar`), `beamer` sets them really late.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, but halfway through the document I start getting "Arithmetic overflow" errors ._. So like, the first 50 pages have the proper "progress bar", and then it fails after that.

Comment: @AramPapazian either use `\tmpbarwidth=\dimexpr\insertpagenumber\barwidth/\mypagecount\relax` instead, or divide first and multiply afterwards.

Comment: So your solution does technically work so I gave you credit. What I did instead was to replace `\insertpresentationendpage` with `\insertdocumentendpage` and then swap multiply and divid as you suggested and it worked. Thanks.